# how to make a epub reader for Android and display?

Tags: android, epub

I got the detailed info for iphone by 
[Reading ePub format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format/8950813#8950813)

but I want to mock it same for the Android, please ping which framework I can use for android??

Note: In iphone all GIF image all are supported, but same epub file runs on android no support for GIF image and many fonts!!!!!!

Comment: You may find an answer from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640728 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546164 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785519

Comment: Thank you :) really helpful, I'm looking for JS parser/readers to build with phonegap, for making that I need a epub unziper(to html+css+jss) for https://github.com/joseph/Monocle code

Comment: you can use the following link for parsing **https://github.com/augustl/js-epub**

Answer (score 2):

How to read epub HTML content

I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want all the content? Or something specific? All the content can be retrieved using Book.getContent().

how to show this on Android (using WebView?),

I would use WebView for this. Haven't tried that myself though.

how to split content into pages

This I don't know what would work best.

how to search the content.

The nl.siegmann.epublib.search package in epublib-tools has code for a simple search functionality.